# Can I self-host my own Ethereum

Tags: go-ethereum

Can I create my own Ethereum with name blah and people can create their tokens with Remix on my own Ethereum (blah)??

Because Ethereum is open source!!!

Comment: Thanks Richard! Do you have any Article or Tutorial that teach how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

> Can I self-host my own Ethereum

Yes.

However, you must adhere to the relevant licensing: https://eth.wiki/en/archive/licensing

Comment: So you say I can and people can create tokens on that without etherscan or any closed source tool? ya?

Comment: And can I own my blah net(like Eth mainnet or testnets)?

Comment: Yes, correct. As long as you stay within the licence conditions.